# Xamarin.forms iOS crashes when trying to take video. Cannot debug

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have this issue where I want to make a video using the montemagno library:

```
 private async void CreateVideo()
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
                return;
            }

            videoFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions
            {
                DesiredLength = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Constants.VIDEOLENGTH),
                Quality = VideoQuality.Low,                
                CompressionQuality = 0
            });            

            if (videoFile == null)
                return;


            //await DisplayAlert("File Location", videoFile.Path, "OK");
            btn_delVideo.IsVisible = true;
            grid_makeVideo.IsVisible = false;

            videoStream = Converters.StreamToByteArray(videoFile.GetStream());

            isVideoSet = true;
            bx_reset.IsVisible = false;
            btn_delVideo.IsVisible = true;


            await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(videoFile.Path);
        }
```

This code works perfectly on android.
On iOS it crashes in production.
I cannot debug this code because it returns. The simulator does NOT have a camera, and therefore can't proceed.

I tried deploying to a real iPhone, but codesigning always failes and those provisioning profiles are the worst in the world.

I know that it at least gets to the point where it displays "no camera" so the initialise function seems to work. Therefore I belelive the issue is at TakeVideoAsync().

It crashes before even showing any camera.

I could really need some help here.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have all the permissions set. AND DONT FORGET MICROPHONE USE ;-)

Comment: Have you resolved your problem, right? Congats.Thanks for your support for xamarin.